# CQ JCR XPath query contains square bracket

Tags: xpath, aem, jcr

I have properties in the repository with values that contain double square brackets.

I'd like to find these using a JCR XPath query (assuming it's possible)

I've tried using the following using the Query tool in CRXDE but there are "no results to display":

```
/jcr:root/content//*[jcr:contains(., '[[')] order by @jcr:score
```

Do I have to escape these characters and if so how?

Thanks, Rick.

Answer (score 0):

`Text.escapeIllegalXpathSearchChars(searchTerm)` should do the trick for the `jcr:contains()` term.

See https://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/EncodingAndEscaping

Comment: Thanks @Alexander I really appreciate the answer but I should have mentioned I'm attempting to use the Query tool in CRXDE. I've updated the original question.